# Getting os.environ to work with Python run via NSSM

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, python-os, nssm

I am stuck on an environment variables mismatch.

I run a Python script on Windows 10 via a program called [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/).

At runtime, I do the following:

1. Load in parameters from a text file
2. Put its contents into the environment using `os.environ.setdefault(name, value)`.
3. Try to load in environment variables using `os.environ[name]`

Result:any variables I added do **not** show up.

I am not sure why the variables I add aren't available.  **Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?**

A starting point is that NSSM uses environment variables from Windows HKLM registry: [source](https://nssm.cc/usage) (see bottom).  I am not sure if this is the reason `os.environ` cannot see relevant variables.

Comment: Please provide a simplified example that reproduces the problem. I have no problem using `os.environ.setdefault` to add environment variables for the current process and child processes, in both Python 2.7 and 3.7, so there must be something particular in what you're doing here, or some misunderstanding about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out that my problem was outside of the scope of this question.  @Recessive and @eryksun **thank you both** for answering, it put me "onto the scent".

It turns out my problem was using Python pathlib's `Path.home()`.

- When running via command prompt, it pulled `HOMEPATH` environment variable.
- When running via NSSM, it pulled `USERPROFILE` environment variable.

This discrepancy in `Path.home()` was the real problem.  It wasn't finding the environment variables because NSSM was looking in a totally different folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble using `os.environ.setdefault` in the past as well. Instead of that, say you were trying to add to the `PATH` environment variable, do the following:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += ";" + the_path_to_the_file
```

EDIT:

Also, for creating a new variable:

```
os.environ['new_var'] = 'text'
```